# the for loop to show x numbers of bars or candles closed upper bollinger

Tags: pine-script

[image]

I can show on the chart, when x numbers of candles or bars, let's say x=5, are closed consecutively above the upper bollinger band, by creating a variable like this one:

`x_closed_above_upper = close > upper and close[1] > upper[1] and close[2] > upper[2] and close[3] > upper[3] and close[4] > upper[4]`

Is it possible to show the same thing by using the for loop, such as `for i=0 to x(=5, in this case) by 1` with `if close[i] > upper`?

I tried it, but my knowledge of using the for loop is quite limited. I would be grateful if somebody knows the answer. Many thanks!

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="x numbers of candles closed consecutively above the upper bollinger band", overlay=true)



length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title='Source')
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title='StdDev')
basis = ta.sma(src, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
offset = input.int(0, 'Offset', minval=-500, maxval=500)
plot(basis, 'Basis', color=color.new(#FF6D00, 0), offset=offset)
p1 = plot(upper, 'Upper', color=color.new(#2962FF, 0), offset=offset)
p2 = plot(lower, 'Lower', color=color.new(#2962FF, 0), offset=offset)
fill(p1, p2, title='Background', color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95))




// Red and Green candles

RedCandle = close <= open
GreenCandle = close >= open


// x numbers of candles closed consecutively above the upper bollinger band

`x_closed_above_upper = close > upper and close[1] > upper[1] and close[2] > upper[2] and close[3] > upper[3]
     and close[4] > upper[4]`


plotshape(x_closed_above_upper ? high : na, title='5 bars closed above the upper bollinger', text='5 bars\nclosed above\nupper bollinger', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), size=size.tiny)

// How is it possible to get the same data by using 
// for i=0 to x(here x would be 5) by 1, etc.?"
// if close[i] > upper ?
// Thank you for your help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop here. Just use a counter and increment its value every time price closes above the upper band. Reset it otherwise.

```
cnt_target = 5
var up_cnt = 0
up_cnt := close > upper ? up_cnt + 1 : 0

plotshape(up_cnt == cnt_target, title='5 bars closed above the upper bollinger', text='5 bars\nclosed above\nupper bollinger', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), size=size.tiny)
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much for your help!